# Embed responsive vimeo video

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vimeo-player

Working with https://codepen.io/malditojavi/pen/BZGVoq - I'm trying to get rid of the padding-bottom extra space created by the [responsive](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/responsive-helpers/) helper class from Bootstrap.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" style="height: 50%;" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/195372563" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>And some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" style="height: 50%;" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/195372563" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>And some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice I added some extra styling code in the iframe lines style="height: 50%;" so I can get rid of the extra black space created by Vimeo.

Comment: You are using in codepen bootstrap -3,  and you are using reference classes of bootstrap -4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this link to embed videos responsively

[embed responsively](http://embedresponsively.com)

Try this

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row videorow">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class='embed-container'><iframe src='http://player.vimeo.com/video/195372563' frameborder='0' webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>And some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

   <div class="row videorow">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class='embed-container'><iframe src='http://player.vimeo.com/video/195372563' frameborder='0' webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>And some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.embed-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.embed-container iframe,
.embed-container object,
.embed-container embed { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.videorow{
  margin:10px auto;
}
```

[Link for reference](https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/awQxrv)
Hope this helps...

Comment: This worked great. Thanks @ChandraShekar. You saved my day.